# Find/Replace character limit workaround in VBA for Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a basic vbscript which finds and replaces in microsoft word, however I am not able to go over a certain amount of characters (I think 256). I was wondering if anyone had any idea of a workaround with this problem. Below is a sample of script I'm using:

```
Sub FixedReplacements()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim SearchString As String
Dim EndString As String
Dim Id As String
Dim Link As String

Rng.Find.ClearFormatting
Rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Rng.Find
    .Text = "" 'find text won't exceed character limitation'
    .Replacement.Text = "" 'replace text won't exceed character limitation'
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Rng.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: Find the first 256 characters, then create a `Range` that extends to the length of your "real" find term, compare the `Text` of the range to your find term, and then set the `Text` of the created `Range` to replace it (instead of `Find.Replace`) with your match. The underlying `Range` objects will not have a character limitation.

Answer (score 2):

To find text that's too long, search the first 255 characters of the string, then extend the found Range to the additional characters. OR break down the string into 255-character "bites" and search them in succession (always extending the first found Range to the end point of each succeeding found range).

Using text that's too long for replacement can be done, but not using `Replace`. Instead, assign the string value to the found range, in a loop. (Note that `Wrap` needs to be set to `wdFindStop`.) Example

```
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim replacementText as String
Dim findText as String, excessText as String
Dim excessChars as Long, bTooLong as Boolean

findText = "Text to be found..."
If Len(findText) > 255 Then
   bToolLong = True
   excessText = Mid(findText, 256)
   excessChars = Len(excessText)
   findText = Left(findText, 255)
End If
replacementText = "some long string greater than 256 characters"
With Rng.Find
    .Text = findText
    '.Replacement.Text = "" 'replace text won't exceed character limitation'
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
bFound = Rng.Find.Execute
Do While bFound
    If bTooLong Then
      Rng.End = Rng.End + excessChars
      'Possible to check findText against the range
      'If Rng.Text <> findText Then 'do something
    End If
    Rng.Text = replacementText
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    bFound = Rng.Find.Execute
Loop
```

Comment: For that, use @Comintern 's suggestion. I'll incorporate the basics of it in my Answer, if that helps...

Comment: @CindyMeister Depending on what the Find text is, it may be amenable to a *wildcard* Find, thus obviating the need for an overly-long Find expression. For example: .Text = "First few words*last few words", with .MatchWildcards = True - and in which case you can also omit MatchCase, MatchWholeWord, MatchSoundsLike, & MatchAllWordForms.

Comment: macropod, Using a wildcard works very well and I will incorporate this into my script. As for @Cindy Meister The script ALMOST works, for some reason when it replaces it doesn't cycle through the rest of the findText other than the first 255 Characters which is then replaced by the replacement text specified. Any fixes for this?
I don't know how to do what Cominten 's suggestion. I'm very new to VB so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelAguilera My code does use Comintern's suggestion... Put a breakpoint at `If bTooLong` then use F8 to step through and see if it "hits" the line(s) inside the `If` the second and following times?

Comment: @CindyMeister Sorry for the mix up. When looking at the script using F8 it does not touch the if statement. Any reason for this?

Comment: You need to provide exact information for reproducing what you want - *in a question*. We can't possibly know what you're trying to do. And if the `If`is not touched then the Find was not successful so execution never enters the loop.

Comment: Okay so when I input a text longer than 255 characters into the findText variable what happens is that it DOES go through the only loop once to replace the first 255 characters and doesn't go through the loop again for the excess characters. The word report consists of many tables which are very messy. My aim is to clean up the contents of each table. There are duplicate sentences which I want to clean up by finding the messy sentence and replacing it with a clean sentence. Your script will find the first 255 characters and replace them. It will not replace any more than that... @CindyMeister

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit in the `Find().Text`. Check this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

    Dim lookFor As String
    lookFor = "The text to be searched for. Use an empty string () to search for formatting only. You can search for special characters by specifying appropriate character codes. For example, corresponds to a paragraph mark and corresponds to a tab character."
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=lookFor, ReplaceWith:="hello", Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

- [Word.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find)

Probably the limiting part is the a line, which is not parsed correctly in the string to look for, thus it is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages looking for a simple solution to this; for the benefit of those also trawling, please consider my solution.

My assumption is that there is one occurrence of the text to be replaced.

1. Find text that you want to replace
2. Insert newtext after
3. Use find and replace, to remove the found text

   ```
   With WordDoc.Content
   .Find.Execute findText:="text", Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
   .InsertAfter Text:="newtext"
   .Find.Execute findText:="text", ReplaceWith:=""
   End With
   ```

Comment: @Chris_F. Without wanting to place too fine a point on it, your 'solution' does not address the OP's need, which is to Find strings of more than 255 characters. Moreover, your approach to what you're doing is very inefficient.