# Replacing larger sections of Word document than 256 characters with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Word document that I am trying to replace placeholder text in with multi-line strings in Powershell. This works fine for small, single line strings, but a string argument must be less than 256 characters so entire paragraphs fail.

The code I'm using is;

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application   
$objWord.Visible = $false

$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\me\document.docx") 
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection 

$MatchCase = $False
$MatchWholeWord = $True
$MatchWildCards = $False
$MatchSoundsLike = $False
$MatchAllWordForms = $False 
$Forward = $True
$wdFindContinue = 1
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
$Format = $False
$wdReplaceNone = 1 
$wdReplaceAll = 2

function ProcessDocument($toFind, $toReplace, $object){   
    $shazam = $objSelection.Find.Execute($toFind,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildCards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,$toReplace,$wdReplaceAll)
}

$findText= "XXXXPLACEHOLDER"

$ReplaceWith= @"
•   The working hours of this project will be between
8:30 AM and 5:30 PM Monday through Friday, except for public holidays.
The daily rate is based on an 8-hour working day. •   Conditions
differing materially from those ordinarily encountered and generally
recognised as inherent in the work of the character provided for in
this Work Order may affect scope, schedule, services deliverables, and
fees. •   These services are provided on a Time and Materials basis.
Any timelines, dates, and/or delivery schedules provided are estimates
only and subject to change.
"@

ProcessDocument($findText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildCards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$wdReplaceAll)
```

What's the better way to do this so I can replace entire sections?

Comment: ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53154781/242520

Comment: Hrm. There's a lot of reasons why this shouldn't be useful (VBA for Word is a different language and treats documents entirely differently) but I wonder if chopping the para up into an array and iterating over it inserting the characters 250 at a time with a sliding-forward placeholder you replace with would work... will have a play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution that attempts to implement @Elomis' approach. Maybe this gets you started.

```
$chunkSize = 255 - $findText.Length
for($i = 0; $i -lt $ReplaceWith.Length - 1; $i += $chunkSize) {
    if ($ReplaceWith.Length - $i -le $chunkSize) {
        $chunk = $ReplaceWith.Substring($i, ($ReplaceWith.Length - $i))
    }
    else {
        $chunk = $ReplaceWith.Substring($i, $chunkSize) + $findText
    }
    ProcessDocument($findText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildCards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,$chunk,$wdReplaceAll)
}
```

Comment: I actually wound up doing ALMOST exactly that, but replacing each chunk with 200 characters at a time, appending '####" on the end of the chunk, so the next iteration of the loop could append to the end of the previous :)

Comment: @Elomis Shouldn't my version do exactly that? I append the replace sequence at the end of the chunk at every iteration. Anyways, glad I could help.