# Passing Multi Line String from Excel To Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am currently trying to pass a multi line string from Excel to a Word document. I create the string first, using cell data and then try to pass this on to Word, by method of search and replace. The code is finding the word in Word (where to replace), but it's replacing it with an empty string. A couple things from this; first, I `Debug.Print` the string when the replacing happens and the string is full in the immediate window. Second, when I replace the word with a simple string it replaces it fine, which leads me to believe there seems to be a problem with the multi line string I am trying to send to Word in the first place. Below is my code and everything else that may be of relevance.

Below is the `For Each` loop that cycles through each worksheet and creates the relevant string per that sheet. `randNo` represents a random row number (as the string is to contain random data). But this is not relevant to the problem.

```
'open the word file
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Documents.Open strPath & fileOpen, ReadOnly:=False
objWord.Visible = True

For Each ws In Worksheets
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'check if enough rows
    If lRow < 11 Then
        myLimit = (lRow - 1)
    Else
        myLimit = 10
    End If
    'cycle through and concatenate string
    For i = 1 To myLimit
        randNo = Int((lRow - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)

        dateStr = ws.Range("A" & randNo).Text
        timeStr = ws.Range("B" & randNo).Text

        conditionString = conditionString & vbNewLine & dateStr & " " & timeStr & " " & GetAllConditions(dateStr, timeStr)
    Next i
    'activate word - ready for search and replace        
    objWord.Activate

    textToFind = "RS" & myCntr

    finalStr = textToFind & conditionString

    With objWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Text = textToFind
        .Replacement.Text = finalStr
        Debug.Print finalStr
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    myCntr = myCntr + 1
    conditionString = ""
Next ws
```

Below is an example of the `finalStr` print out from the Immediate window in VBE:

```
RS7
25/09/2018 08:00:00 C2, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, 
06/08/2018 08:00:00 C4, C6, C7, 
25/01/2019 14:30:00 C1, C2, C5, C6, C7, C8, C11, 
05/11/2018 08:00:00 C6, C7, 
31/12/2018 20:30:00 C1, C2, C6, C7, C8, C10, C11, 
30/11/2018 08:00:00 C2, C6, C7, C8, 
25/09/2018 08:00:00 C2, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, 
11/02/2019 14:30:00 C1, C4, C6, C7, C8, 
01/10/2018 14:30:00 C1, C2, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C11, 
11/09/2018 14:30:00 C1, C2, C3, C4, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11,
```

Again, it finds the `textToFind` variable fine, but just replaces it with an empty string instead of the required (above) string.

I am not sure as to the cause of this, or what I am missing or not understanding (as I must be being a dummy here!) so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK Word have a 256 character limitation in find replacement method. Your string is around around 461 char in length, after truncating it to 255 char it is working. May refer [Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050902/runtime-error-5854-string-parameter-is-too-long) and.[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154314/find-replace-character-limit-workaround-in-vba-for-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character limit on Find & Replace is 255 and you can get around it on the Replace function by using the Clipboard. This only works for replacement text. The "^c" control does not work in the Find Text function.

Add to your code the following:

```
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
'Put string variable content on the clipboard
DataObj.SetText finalStr
DataObj.PutInClipboard
With objWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .Text = textToFind
    .Replacement.Text = "^c"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

'clear the clipboard
DataObj.SetText " "
DataObj.PutInClipboard
```

Comment: This is great, thanks @Rich Michaels. Managed to get this working and saves a lot of effort.